# Examples of the dihedral group $D_4$ acting on sets

Tags: group-theory, group-actions, dihedral-groups

Consider the group $D_4$.  Give examples of $D_4$ acting on a set.

Attempt:  So $|D_4| = 8$.  I have come up with a few, but I was wondering what some people here thought.
First one we came up with in class was $D_4$ acting on the set of vertices of a square.  Am I correct in saying $D_4$ acts on this set because there are eight symmetries of the square and 8 elements in $D_4$.  So each element corresponds to a symmetry.

I think I can extend this to an octagon, which has 8 faces, and so each element can correspond to a face.

Another one I came up with was the set of edges on a cube.  Each element in $D_4$ can correspond to an edge.

Is my reasoning correct above for why $D_4$ could act on these sets? Can anybody suggest others?

Many thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To define a group action, you need:

1) A group $G$ (In you case, $G = D_4$ is fixed.)

2) A set $X$ (you gave several suggestions, like the set of vertices of a square).

3) A multiplication rule $G\times X \to X$ satisfying the axioms of a group action.

In your suggestions, I'm missing 3).

Comment: In 3),you mean a mapping $X \times G \to X$.

Comment: Thanks, I've changed it (I went with the left action).

Comment: I know what the two group axioms are but I am struggling to put elements of $G$ and $X$ together to create an action. For the set of vertices perhaps I could say let $g_1 \in G$ be a reflection through vertex 1 and $g_2 \in G$ be the identity.  I think this satisfies the group action defintion.

Comment: There is a *natural* action of the $D_8$ on the set of points of the real plane. This action represents the symmetries of a square: Four elements act as the rotation by $0$ (identity), $\pm\pi/2$ and $\pi$, and four act as reflections (about the $x$- and the $y$-axis and the two diagonals). This action can be restricted to certain subsets of the plane, like the four vertices of a square. In general you need a union of orbits under the action.

Comment: I am struggling to find more group actions.  I mean what sort of things should I be looking for when looking for group actions associated with $D_4$?

Comment: As I said: You could just stick with the natural action on the plane (as described above), and restrict the point set. Then for example: $D_4$ acts on the full plane, $D_4$ acts on the vertices of a square, $D_4$ acts on the vertices of a circle, $D_4$ acts on the origin (a single point, i.e. the action is trivial) etc.

Comment: How do you know that the above are necessarily group actions?

Comment: Because if you apply the $8$ mappings represented by the group elements, you stay within all the given sets. Maybe a counterexample helps: The restriction of the natural action of the $D_4$ to the $x$-axis is *not* a group action (why?). BTW: If this discussion is of any help for you, please consider to upvote my answer.

Comment: Is it because if you rotate a point by pi/2 on the x axis, you end up on the y axis? Or, for some practice in using the axioms, a rotation of a point on the x axis and then reflecting about x axis will give a point on -y.  But rotating and then reflecting leaves a point on the axis in it's original place.  So by the axioms it isn't a group action. Is this right?

Comment: Yeah, applying the group elements to the points of the $x$-axis, you may end up with a point not on the $x$-axis. This is not allowed.

Comment: How could you think of sets that are not contained in the natural action?

Comment: For example, each group acts on itself by left-multiplication. In this way you get an action of $D_4$ on $D_4$.

Comment: That makes sense.  Could $D_4$ act on the triangle somehow? If so, I would need to find 8 actions on the triangle that preserve the triangle

Comment: Restriction of the natural action to a triangle won't work. But the trivial action (its multiplication rule is $g\cdot x = x$ for all $g\in S_4$ and all $x\in X$) works on *any* set, so this would give a (quite boring) action of $D_4$ on the triangle.

Comment: What about trying to find an action on the triangle? (I.e the natural action may not work, but how can I be sure there isn't another action)?

Comment: Come on, I have just given you an action on the triangle.

Comment: Sorry, I meant a non trivial one.

Comment: There are others on the triangle. I think you should go ahead now on your own.

Comment: Okay I will think about it.  Just to clarify though:  for any action of $D_4$ on a set X, I need to find 8 elements that does something to X, such that every element will keep me in X? Also, thanks for your patience and help.

Comment: Moreover, the axioms of a group action must hold. If restricting a known action, nothing can go wrong exept that elements might be mapped to something outside of the restricted set X. If you construct a new action from scratch, you have to do the full program.

Comment: This comment thread is getting a bit long. Would adding some of the subsequent clarification into the answer improve it?

Comment: I am reading that if $X = D_4$ and $y = (gx, xg, xg^{-1}, g^{-1}x, gxg^{-1}, g^{-1}xg)$ then something to do with these elements qualifies as an action.  It doesen't say what y is or what any of the elements mean.  Can you make any sense out of it?

Answer (score 1):

> Am I correct in saying $D_4$ acts on this set because there are eight symmetries of the square and 8 elements in $D_4$. So each element corresponds to a symmetry.

No, this is not correct: there are other eight-element groups, e.g. the cyclic group of order 8 or the quaternion group, that don't correspond to symmetries of the square. It is crucial that there is a pairing of group elements with symmetries in such a way that they *compose meaningfully*, i.e. that the symmetry paired with $xy$ is the symmetry paired with $y$ followed by the symmetry paired with $x$.

To find more group actions, recall that a group action is *faithful* when the only element that doesn't do anything is the identity, and in particular group actions do not need to be faithful – not all of the elements of the group need to act in an interesting way.

Answer (score 0):

The group $D_4$ acts on $ℝ^2$. As the members are bijections from $$ℝ^2→ℝ^2 : x↦ρ^iσ^j :i ∈\{0,1,2,3 \},j∈\{0,1\}  $$ where $ρ$ is the standard rotation and $σ$ a relection.

Define the group action as the map $$D_8 ×ℝ^2→ ℝ^2:(ρ^iσ^j,x) ↦ρ^iσ^j.x=ρ^iσ^j(x)$$

Let $x ∈ℝ^2$ , then $e.x=e(x)=ρ^0σ^0(x)=x$.
And let $g_1,g_2∈D_4$ then,
$$g_1.(g_2.x)=g_1.(g_2(x))=g_1( g_2 (x))=g_1 \circ g_2 (x)$$